# How can I delete a podcast episode from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, podcasts

I have an iPhone and an iPod. I'm subscribed to one podcast. My iPod is set up to download the 10 most recent unplayed, and the iPhone is set to download the 10 least recent unplayed.

One night, I was listening to an episode of the podcast on my iPhone and I downloaded two more recent podcasts. I was at home, so it downloaded them through my wireless connection, not through iTunes.

However, I can't get the iPhone to get rid of those podcasts. When I would sync the podcast, my iPhone would list 12 episodes, not just 10. And the two downloaded podcasts can't be played back (whenever I try, it immediately kicks me back to the podcast selection screen, as if the episode is over).

I have tried unsyncing the podcast (it removes the 10, but not the broken two). I've tried setting up my iPhone for manual control, and when I try to overwrite the broken podcasts, they will work. However, when I then try to delete them, they stay in the list and go back to being broken.

Can someone offer some help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the listing on the iPhone for the podcasts, swipe your finger from left to right on the episodes you want to delete. A delete button will appear. Is this what you mean when you say you've deleted them?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you mark it listened to in iTunes...  And the two files that can't be played, are you sure that they are good files?  Can you listen to them in iTunes.  Generally damaged files are skipped by the iPhone/iPod...  Which sounds like what you are describing...

Comment: They may have been damaged, but even when I tried to repair them by copying the episode to the iPhone, followed by deleting them, the bad link would reappear.